# Boas práticas/maneira correta de realizar upgrade da base local

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Bom dia, peguei um APP iniciado por um colega na empresa. O problema é que não estou voando ainda com android. Estou precisando fazer alterações na estrutura do banco local (Com o APP em produção), a minha dúvida fica na execução do método onUpgrade. Vou tentar descrever o cenário do APP quando peguei:
Cada arquivo dos Models possui um outro arquivo DBHandler, que faz a iteração com o banco (Inserções, consultas...). Cada DBHandler tinha o CREATE TABLE das tabelas referentes ao seu Model, além de todos possuírem as variáveis:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION_PGS = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME_PGS = "database.bd";
```

Eu não via sentido em deixar assim em todos os DBHandler, visto que em cada mudança de versão teria que alterar todos os arquivos. Criei um central que armazena essas informações e pego elas nessas variáveis. O problema é que quando eu mudo a versão nesse arquivo, o método onUpgrade não é executado.
A questão é, fiz da forma errada? Qual a melhor/correta forma?  Toda documentação que vi dizia - resumindo - que o onUpgrade era o metodo utilizado para atualizar estrutura de banco e para isso era só alterar a versão.

Segue trecho de codigo do arquivo FamiliesDBHandler, depois que eu centralizei essas informações:

```
public class FamiliesDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION_PGS = Config.getDatabaseVersion();
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME_PGS = Config.getDatabaseName();

        public static final String TABLE_NAME_PGS_FAMILIES = "families";
        public static final String COLUMN_ID_PGS_FAMILIES = "_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_PGS_FAMILIES = "name";
        public static final String COLUMN_CPF_PGS_FAMILIES = "cpf";
        public static final String COLUMN_COUNTY_PGS_FAMILIES = "county";
        public static final String COLUMN_CODE_PGS_FAMILIES = "pgs_code";
        public static final String COLUMN_COUNTY_CODE_PGS_FAMILIES = "county_code";
        public static final String COLUMN_LATITUDE_PGS_FAMILIES = "latitude";
        public static final String COLUMN_LONGITUDE_PGS_FAMILIES = "longitude";
        public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL_OWNER = "email_owner";

        public FamiliesDBHandler(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME_PGS, null, DATABASE_VERSION_PGS);
            this.createTableIfNotExistPgs(this.getWritableDatabase());


        }

        public FamiliesDBHandler(Context context, String type){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME_PGS, null, DATABASE_VERSION_PGS);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){}
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
            Log.i("EMATERPGS", "UPGRADE");
            String ALTER_TABLE = "ALTER TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME_PGS_FAMILIES +" ADD COLUMN "+COLUMN_EMAIL_OWNER+" STRING" ;
            try{
                db.execSQL(ALTER_TABLE);
            }catch(SQLiteException e){
                Log.i("EMATERPGS", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public boolean createTableIfNotExistPgs(SQLiteDatabase db){
            boolean returnStatus = true;

            String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME_PGS_FAMILIES +" (" +
                    COLUMN_ID_PGS_FAMILIES +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    COLUMN_NAME_PGS_FAMILIES +" TEXT," +
                    COLUMN_CPF_PGS_FAMILIES +" TEXT," +
                    COLUMN_COUNTY_PGS_FAMILIES +" TEXT," +
                    COLUMN_CODE_PGS_FAMILIES +" INTEGER," +
                    COLUMN_COUNTY_CODE_PGS_FAMILIES +" TEXT," +
                    COLUMN_LATITUDE_PGS_FAMILIES +" DOUBLE," +
                    COLUMN_LONGITUDE_PGS_FAMILIES +" DOUBLE);";
            try{
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            }catch(SQLiteException e){
                returnStatus = false;
            }

            return returnStatus;
        }
}
```

Arquivo onde centralizei as informações:

```
public class Config {
    //DATABASE
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";

    public static int getDatabaseVersion() {
        return DATABASE_VERSION;
    }

    public static String getDatabaseName() {
            return DATABASE_NAME;
    }
}
```

[EDIT]
Uma informação que pode ser relevante no caso:
Quando eu mudo a versão em todos os arquivos, ex.:
Passo de

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION_PGS = 1;
```

para

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION_PGS = 2;
```

o onUpgrade não é executado, porém quando eu altero em apenas um arquivo, o onUpgrade daquele arquivo é executado, mas ai da erro no APP (Acredito por ter mais de uma versão de banco no código).

Comment: Acho que sua questão poderia ser mais completa se você colocasse o seu código para analisarmos. Esta questão do OnUpgrade é muito ampla e depende muito de como está implementando o banco de dados se é via Helper ou se é usando um ORM.

Comment: Pra ser sincero, pra mim não funciou alter table, eu precisei criar uma nova tabela de backup, passar os valores da tabela antiga, deletar e criar a tabela antiga com alguma nova coluna que queira, e repassar os valores da tabela backup pra essa nova tabela, depois deletar a tabela backup. Pra mim essa foi a única solução.

Comment: Ok, encontrei o motivo. Na Activity Main do APP todos os *DBHandler são estanciados (pela lógica, para que todo banco fosse criado) acontece que quando eu mudo a versão do banco o onUpgrade roda, porém só roda o da primeira instancia. Todas as demais instancias não fazem a execução do onUpgrade. Isso pq na prática, o banco é atualizado na primeira instancia. Posso tentar ser mais claro

Comment: Valeu Murilo, vi bastante disso durante minha pesquisa. Mas não era o meu caso. É que como o APP foi todo desenvolvido por outra pessoa, dificultou meu entendimento. Mas só o fato de eu fazer a pergunta aqui auxiliou na forma como eu olhava para o código..

Comment: Entendi, se encontrou o problema, seria interessante responder a sua própria pergunta, para ajudar outros com o mesmo problema ou parecido.

Comment: Sim, concordo. É que ainda tenho uma duvida quanto à forma que o banco é criado. Na minha mainActivity todos os *DBHandler são criados como falei no outro comentário. Cada DBHandler cria uma tabela:
`activitiesDBHandler = new ActivitiesDBHandler(getBaseContext());`

`familiesDBHandler = new FamiliesDBHandler(getBaseContext());`

`familyActivitiesDBHandler = new familyActivitiesDBHandler(getBaseContext());`

Ou seja, quando eu mudo a versão do banco apenas a primeira instancia vai rodar o onUpgrade. Essa é a questão, eu deveria migrar a criação do banco todo em um arquivo só?

Comment: Nisso não posso ajudar, não sei se é melhor prática, mas eu costumo criar em um único DBHandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de fazer essa pergunta e seguir buscando respostas na web, prestei mais atenção no código da minha mainActivity. Acontece que lá, todos esses *DBHandler são instanciados (Codigo abaixo), acredito que com o intuito de que todo o banco fosse criado.

```
//DATABASE//
        try{
            activitiesDBHandler = new ActivitiesDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            familiesDBHandler = new FamiliesDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            familyActivitiesDBHandler = new FamilyActivitiesDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            activityProductTypesDBHandler = new ProductTypesDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            costTypesDBHandler = new CostTypesDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            areaTypesDBHandler = new AreaTypesDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            laborForceDBHandler = new LaborForceDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            laborForceTypesDBHandler = new LaborForceTypesDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            animalDBHandler = new AnimalDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            animalTypeDBHandler = new AnimalTypeDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            expenseDBHandler = new ExpenseDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            otherRecipeTypeDBHandler = new OtherRecipeTypeDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            managementPlainPeriodDBHandler = new ManagementPlainPeriodDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            managementPlainDBHandler = new ManagementPlainDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            planningMatrixDBHandler = new PlanningMatrixDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            planningMatrixActionDBHandler = new PlanningMatrixActionDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            plannedSituationDBHandler = new PlannedSituationDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            calendarOfActionDBHandler = new CalendarOfActionDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            calendarOfActionYearsDBHandler = new CalendarOfActionYearsDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            buildingMachineDBHandler = new BuildingMachineDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            indirectExpenseDBHandler = new IndirectExpenseDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            logsDBHandler = new LogsDBHandler(getBaseContext());
            localLoginDBHandler = new LocalLoginDBHandler(getBaseContext());
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            Log.i("TAG", "ERROR "+e.getMessage());
        }
        //DATABASE//
```

Como todos esses *DBHAndler extendem a classe *SQLiteOpenHelper*, cada um deles possui seus métodos onCreate e onUpgrade. E quando eu alterava a versão do banco no meu arquivo central de configurações o APP rodava sim o onUpgrade, porém só o onUpgrade da primeira instancia. Nas demais instancias a versão do banco já está atualizada, por isso o metodo não é chamado. Nesse meu caso eu resolvi deixando a instancia da tabela que eu queria mudar como a primeira da fila. 
É um caso bem especifico e particular eu acredito, mas espero que ajude alguém a não fazer dessa forma. Pois no momento que eu precisar mudar várias tabelas do banco, essa forma de desenvolvimento não vai me permitir. Acredito que a melhor forma seria passar toda a criação da estrutura da base para apenas um arquivo.